# How do I execute the saving of time function once?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Right now the code runs so that the time is saved in shared preferences so it can load that specific time that is saved. However, when you leave the activity and come back to it the time resets to the current time and does not load the saved time. 
Here is my code (this part is on my oncreate):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("MyData2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String clockedout = sharedPreferences2.getString("clockedout",DEFAULT);

if(clockedout.equals(DEFAULT)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No hours logged today.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
    SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US);
    format.setLenient(false);
}

//Here is the button that is saving the time:
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
    if(b) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");                
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        TextView clockedin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clockedin);
        clockedin.setText(formattedDate);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tb.isChecked());
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1= sharedPreferences2.edit();
        editor1.putString("clockedin", formattedDate);
        editor1.commit();
    } else {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        TextView clockedout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clockedout);
        clockedout.setText(formattedDate);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", false);
        editor.commit();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("MyData2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1= sharedPreferences2.edit();
        editor1.putString("clockedout", clockedout.getText().toString());
        editor1.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want , just copy and paste it.

activity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/white"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <Switch
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:id="@+id/switch_button"
   android:textSize="30dp"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clockedin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="clocked_in : "
    android:textSize="30dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_clockedin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="last_clocked_in : shows on restart app"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clockedout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="clocked_out : "
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
 {

String DEFAULT = "def";
Switch switch_btn;
TextView clocked_in,clocked_out,last_clockedin;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2;
Spinner spinner;
  static  String fileName = "my_flags";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = new Spinner(this);
    spinner.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

    switch_btn = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_button);
    clocked_in = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockedin);
    clocked_out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockedout);
    last_clockedin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_clockedin);

    switch_btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


        if(readFromPrefrences(this,"clockedout",DEFAULT).equals(DEFAULT))   {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hours logged today.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
       clocked_out.setText("last clocked out : "+readFromPrefrences(this,"clockedout",DEFAULT));
    }

    if(readFromPrefrences(this,"clockedin",DEFAULT).equals(DEFAULT)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No last logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        last_clockedin.setText("last clocked in : "+readFromPrefrences(this,"clockedin",DEFAULT));
    }

}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
    if(buttonView.isChecked()) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        clocked_in.setText("clock_in : " + formattedDate);
        saveToPrefrences(this, "clockedin", formattedDate);


    } else {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        saveToPrefrences(this, "clockedout", formattedDate);
        if (!readFromPrefrences(this,"clockedout",DEFAULT).equals(DEFAULT))
        clocked_out.setText(readFromPrefrences(this,"clockedout",DEFAULT));


    }


}

    public static void saveToPrefrences(Context context, String key, String value)
{
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(fileName ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit =  sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.putString(key,value);
    edit.apply();
}

    public static String readFromPrefrences(Context context,String key, String default_value)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  context.getSharedPreferences(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key,default_value);
    }


}
```

Comment: it only loads the clocked out time. It does not load the clock in time if you leave the activity and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Why it happens:

**onCheckedChanged** called everytime when state getting changed.

You just need to work with **onClickListener** instead of **onCheckedChanged**.

Say for an Example:

```
   CheckBox checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(checkBox.isChecked()){

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                System.out.println(c.getTime());
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                TextView clockedin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clockedin);
                clockedin.setText(formattedDate);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", tb.isChecked());
                editor.commit();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1= sharedPreferences2.edit();
                editor1.putString("clockedin", formattedDate);
                editor1.commit();
            } else {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                System.out.println(c.getTime());
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
                TextView clockedout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clockedout);
                clockedout.setText(formattedDate);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("toggleButton", false);
                editor.commit();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2=getSharedPreferences("MyData2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1= sharedPreferences2.edit();
                editor1.putString("clockedout", clockedout.getText().toString());
                editor1.commit();
            }
         }
    });
```

Hope this will help you